# Adding a note to Request sample in OpenAPI

Tags: api, swagger, openapi

Is it possible to add a note to the field where the Request Samples show on Swagger UI?

My API is described in the following way:

```
  /v1/test:
post:
  summary:test
  tags:
    - test
  description: test
  parameters:
    - in: body
      name: body
      required: false
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/test'
  x-code-samples:
    - lang: cURL
      source: >-
```

When the yaml is rendered by our UI program, the Request sample is shown like this:

[sample request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWqyS.png)

Is it possible to add a note someplace marked in red on the image?

I have tried adding x-description and x-summary, but that doesn't work.

I wonder if this is possible at all.

Thank you

Comment: What doc renderer are you using? ReDoc?

Comment: I am using Netlify connected to Jekyll